# Не работает условие if

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Приветствую. Есть код:

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul class="products-list" data-lang="<?php echo $lang ?>">
  <?php echo $yith_woocompare->obj->list_products_html(); ?>
</ul>
```

который по умолчанию выводит html:

```
<ul class="products-list" data-lang=""><li>Не выбраны блюда для сравнения</li></ul>
```

хочу добавить обработчик по условию:

```
    <?php if( $yith_woocompare->obj->list_products_html() !="
<li>Не выбраны товары для сравнения</li>") { ?>
```

но не прокатывает..

Методом тыка выяснил, что условие отрабатывается только после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: он, наверное, выводит и вот это `<ul class="products-list" data-lang="">`

Comment: $yith_woocompare это что? Может у него есть метод `is_empty()` ? Потому что то, как вы ходите сделать, не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что проблема в том, что выводит он что-то про блюда, а проверяете вы что-то про товары :)))

```
<li>Не выбраны блюда для сравнения</li>
<li>Не выбраны товары для сравнения</li>
```

Comment: нет, просто я в выводе вопроса ошибся